# What is the difference between the nd_pdo_mysql and pdo_mysql extensions?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For some reason the *pdo_mysql* PHP extension, on our hosted server, fails to run a query that uses a MySQL view, with this error message.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1615 Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared

(There is a discussion on [Bug #42041 Prepared-Statement fails when MySQL-Server under load](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42041), as well as numerous questions on Stack Overflow.)

For some reason, the query using the view runs just fine, if we switch to using the *nd_pdo_mysql* extension, which is for the MySQL Native Driver (*mysqlnd*).

What is the difference between *pdo_mysql* and *nd_pdo_mysql*? Why would one be chosen over the other one?

Thanks.

Comment: This might help: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.overview.php

Comment: @HaydenSchiff, thanks, but the linked article seems not to relate to pdo drivers. Any more help out there with the differences between the pdo_mysql and nd_pdo_mysql drivers?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "nd_pdo_mysql". Backend libraries are normally compiled into PHP, it's not something you can choose in runtime. Are you using some third-party PHP distribution?

Comment: To whoever Googles here: `nd_pdo_mysql` appears to be a custom plugable extension provided by the [cPanel](https://www.cpanel.com/) hosting platform in order to opt-in the MySQL Native Driver in run-time. In regular PHP setups, the MySQL driver is chosen in [compile time](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.install.php) and it cannot be changed afterwards, thus `pdo_mysql` is the only extension available and doesn't imply anything about the driver.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To connect to your MySQL server from PHP, there are two versions of drivers:

1. `mysqlnd`
2. `libmysql`

In order to connect to your MySQL server  using `mysqlnd` driver, you use the `nd_pdo_mysql` extension, as seen in below screenshot.

[image]

Since `libmysql` returns numeric types as strings, I use `mysqlnd` with `nd_pdo_mysql` in order to get native/strict data, so that numeric types are **NOT** returned as Strings.

From the MySQL official website:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/

> The MySQL native driver for PHP `mysqlnd` is a drop-in replacement for the MySQL Client Library `libmysql` for the PHP script language.

Comment: > Since libmysql returns numeric types as strings, I use mysqlnd with nd_pdo_mysql in order to get native/strict data, so that numeric types are NOT returned as Strings.

----- I have not found this info elsewhere, and am happy now to have some understanding of why one would choose to use nd_pdo_mysql over pdo_mysql. Thank you.

Comment: What software does this screenshot belong to?

Comment: It is from cPanel

Comment: Very helpful answer, also do not forget to set PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = false and PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES = false in the PDO options