# Swift 4 - Convert 1 or 0 from mysql to bool

Tags: ios, swift

I have this variable here, its an Any

```
 item["completed"]
```

Its either 1 or 0 which is true or false from mysql database, how can I covert the 1 or 0 to true or false?

I have tried this:

```
 (item["completed"] as! NSNumber).boolValue)
```

but I get this error

> Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x10f906560) to
>   'NSNumber' (0x10e455d40).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060097/converting-int-to-bool check @lingchen comments.

Comment: The error message indicates that `item["completed"]` is a *string* and not a number.

Comment: Please `print(item["completed"])` so we can see what the value really is.

Comment: print(item["completed"]) prints out 1

Comment: @user979331 cast it as String. `let completed =  item["completed"] as? String == "1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below extension which i have implemented,

```
extension String {

    var bool: Bool {
        return self == "1" ? true : false
    }
}

 (item["completed"] as? String).bool
```

Hope this way may help you.

Comment: This should solve the problem. 

But assuming `1` as `true` and all the others as `false` is a mistake if we talk about computer science. An empty string and/or null/nil string should be false and any other string should be true.

Comment: @ArdaOğulÜçpınar what about “0”?

Comment: @Nate and zero of course. You can see in my answer.

Comment: @Nate i have used ternary condition if you have any value other than "1" then you always get false try this solution first.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
let isCompleted = "1" == (item["completed"] as? String)
```

If you are using `Decodable` for json parsing, you can use following `ApiBool` struct instead of `Bool`

```
struct ApiBool: Codable {
    let value: Bool

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()

        if let string = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self.value = string == "1"
        } else {
            let intVal = try container.decode(Int.self)
            self.value = intVal == 1
        }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(self.value ? 1 : 0)
    }
}
```

**Note** As mentioned in comments, you got an `String` data type and it is expected to be an integer, this is caused by `libmysql` driver, you can connect to MySQL using `mysqlnd` driver instead, this will result in a JSON with proper numeric data types, following posts might help you configure the driver

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46690317/1244597

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45366230/1244597

Answer (score 0):

@ahemadabbas-vagh shared a good and reusable approach. But if we talk about computer science, a string's Boolean equality should not be measured like that.

This approach is the same as his, but it asks `Bool` if the value is true or false, not to `String`. `Bool` should know is a value is true or false, not `String`.

```
var str = "1"

extension Bool {
  static func from(stringValue str: String) -> Bool {
    return str == "1"
  }
}

if Bool.from(stringValue: str) {
  print("TRUE")
} else {
  print("FALSE")
}
```

But it is still not correct. In computer science, null/nil or/and an empty string should be false and any other strings should be true. You can add the string `"0"` to this set.

You can implement like this; better approaches still might exist.
The idea is; globally a string can only be converted to `true` if it is not "0", not "" (empty string), not null/nil or if it is "true".

```
var str = "1" // check for nil, empty string and zero; these should be false; any other string should be true.

extension Bool {

  static func from(stringValue str: String) -> Bool {

    if str == "true" {
      return true
    }

    guard let intVal = Int(str) else {
      return false
    }
    return Bool(truncating: intVal as NSNumber)
  }
}

if Bool.from(stringValue: str) {
  print("TRUE")
} else {
  print("FALSE")
}
```

If you use `Decodable` protocol; I know you know how to handle but:

```
struct aStruct: Decodable {

  let boolVal: Bool

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case completed
  }

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    let boolString = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .completed)
    self.boolVal = Bool.from(stringValue: boolString)
  }

}
```

Comment: Basically your suggestion is correct but mysql returns reliably either `"0"` or `"1"` as Bool value, nothing else.

Comment: Yes, these already and also covers that. Check on a playground. Any code you have implement need to be reusable and fit to computer science as much as possible. I'm trying to give you something suits this idea.